# Where should you be instantiating UI controls from data objects when not an ItemsControl subclass?

Tags: c#, wpf, panel, itemscontrol, itemcontainergenerator

### TLDR version...

We're trying to create as basic Panel subclass with an observable Items property. The control then uses those data items to create ***one or more*** related child UI objects ***per data item***.

Our first thought naturally was to simply subclass ItemsControl, but that doesn't seem to fit because it uses an ItemContainerGenerator which only generates one 'container' per item whereas again, we need to potentially create several (which aren't containers anyway.)  Plus, all the created items have to be direct children on the panel, not held in a container which is why we can't go the route of data templates.

As such, I'm just using a standard Control and I'm trying to find the proper place/event where I should be instantiating/destroying the resulting child UI elements in response to changes in the Items collection.

### Now the details...

First things first.  If there was something like a ItemMultiContainerGenerator, that would be perfect, but I know of no such thing.

Ok, so simply monitor the collection for changes and put the UI generation in the CollectionChanged event!  Right?  That was our first guess too.  The problem there is for every new 'Add' or 'Remove', we have to spin through all existing controls to 'defrag' certain indexing properties on them (think along the lines of a Grid.Row or ZIndex property) meaning if you add ten items, you run the defrag ten times, not once at the end.

Plus, that change event may come in on a different thread. If you attempted to dispatch to the main thread, your performance takes a nose-dive.

Our other attempt was to use MeasureOverride, since that was called only once in response to an InvalidateMeasure call, regardless of how many children we added or removed.  The issues (there are many) with this approach is we lose context of whether something was added or removed, meaning we had to throw away all children and re-add back all new ones making this extremely inefficient.  Plus, mucking around with the visual tree or setting bindings could cause the layout pass to execute multiple times since we were changing something that affects the layout, namingly the panels children.

What I'm trying to find is something that happens as part of the overall rendering process (i.e. from the time the control is told its invalid until it renders), but before the Measure/Layout passes are called. That way I can cache the adds/removes in the CollectionChanged event and simply mark the control as invalid, wait for this mystery event, then process the changes en mass, then send off the results to the layout engine and be done with it.

Using Reflector, I've tried to find out where the ItemsControl adds its children to the panel, but I didn't get too far considering the complexity of the control/ItemContainerGenerator pairing.

So where is the best place to create/add UI elements to a control based on data item changes?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Can you post a screenshot? If you need "several items per item", why don't you just handle this at the viewmodel level and skip all the pain?

Comment: `Plus, all the created items have to be direct children on the panel` - You can override `GetContainerForItemOverride()` on the `ItemsControl`. Anyways I don't see any reason why you care about how the Visual tree is formed.

Comment: Easiest way to explain is with an over-simplified case.  Say we have an object called NameValuePair with a Name and Value, both of type string.  Our control has a property called NameValuePairs.  Using those pairs, the control creates a TextBlock for the name and one for value for each.  Since they are all children of the same panel, we can align all the names up and all the values up during the layout pass.  If we used an ItemsControl, the two TextBlocks would have to be in a container element, then you'd have to figure out how to align controls at different levels in the visual tree.

Comment: Again, that's a simple example that generates two visuals per data item.  Our actual use-case can generate x number of visuals per data item.

Comment: Another thing.  If I'm correct, GetContainerForItemOverride doesn't actually take the item.  It can't because it's the ItemContainerGenerator that maintains the pairing of items to containers, not the containers themselves.

Comment: sounds to me like you're creating some kind of "property grid" or something like that. You should do this with a standard ItemsControl, and using [SharedSizeGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.definitionbase.sharedsizegroup.aspx).

Comment: That's an interesting piece of information, but as I said, that's a simple example. You're focusing on the grid instead of what I'm asking.  Consider another example: a collection of TargetResult objects, each which contains one or more target points which are to be represented as circles on the canvas, all displayed with the same color per TargetResult.  Again, one ObservableCollection<TargetResult> which renders multiple children (the circles) per item.

Comment: That's really easier to handle at the ViewModel level, by creating the appropiate relationships between, say `TargetResult` objects (one-to many). You're thinking the UI as data, which it is not.

Comment: I disagree.  An items control doesn't build ViewModels for its containers.  It generates containers for its ViewModels.  I need multiple 'containers'.  My question is where should those controls be created/managed, yet you keep going back to the data even though the data is irrelevant. Just as a listbox doesn't care what's thrown at it, we don't care what we throw at this.  We just look for certain properties which determine what controls to generate. The control, not the ViewModel manages the views.  This question is about the views.  You're focusing on the wrong thing.

Comment: you're free to take whatever approach you want, I'm just saying you're  overcomplicating everything by doing it that way. Anyways I'm not completely sure I understand what you're after. A screenshot or something would really help

Comment: Again, I disagree about the over-complication step.  Quite the contrary: this simplifies the dev's experience by moving the control creation to the control the same as a normal ItemsControl does.  Again, the only difference is multiple containers per data item.  Everything else is exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're going to have to listen to collection changes manually. There are a few reasons:

- Changing your visual children will invalidate your layout. If you change your children in measure or arrange, you will have an infinite loop.
- Rendering happens **after** layout. By changing children after layout you are asking for an infinite loop.

Hopefully you won't have to support any collections other than `ObservableCollection`, because it is obviously easier to deal with the one type of collection. But, I think you can definitely make a responsive control that will do these things. Here are some tips

- Implement a custom `Collection` that has support for `AddRange` and `RemoveRange` (the INotifyCollectionChanged event supports multiple items being added or removed) so you don't have to do the same work 10 times for 10 new items.
- In your collection change handler, use the e.AddedItems and e.RemovedItems instead of accessing the underlying collection. This will prevent you from receiving exceptions due to the collection changing while you're enumerating it.
- Use BeginInvoke to prevent blocking the producer thread when dispatching back to the UI thread
- To address your initialization concerns, implement `ISupportInitialize`, and use it to suspend your "defrag" process if you have to add or remove multiple items one at a time. WPF will automatically add the Begin/End calls for you when your control is created in XAML.
- Derive from `FrameworkElement` if you don't want a `ControlTemplate`. Lower overhead.
- If this still isn't working because the speed at which your underlying collection changes is too fast, and children are fairly simple, perhaps you should draw them in `OnRender`

One other option that just occurred to me is that you can schedule all these operations on the `Dispatcher`, so that if multiple changes happen, you would only need to do it once. Basically, you would store a reference to the operation like so:

```
private DispatcherOperation pendingDefragOperation;

protected void ScheduleDefrag()
{
    if (pendingDefragOperation == null)
    {
        pendingDefragOperation = Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( 
            DispatcherPriority.Render, // You may want to play around with this
            new Action(Defrag));
    }
}
```

And you would call this on a `CollectionChanged`. And in your `Defrag` call, you'd set `pendingDefragOperation` to null.

Comment: Those are really good tips, pretty much all of which I'm already doing, but I wasn't familiar with the `ISupportInitialize` interface, so voting you up for that one (although it doesn't seem applicable to what I'm trying to do since this isn't related to initialization.) Also, we're deriving from Panel so templates aren't an issue either.  And of course rendering happens after layout.  I'm referring to the overall rendering process which includes measure and layout as part of the process.  I clarified my text to better explain what I meant.  Finally... (see next comment)

Comment: ...Assuming you've set the 'ContentProperty' attribute on your control to your 'Items' property, if you define your collection in XAML like this <SomeControl><SomeDataItem/><SomeDataItem/><SomeDataItem/></SomeControl>, you get three 'Add' actions with one item each in your CollectionChanged handler, not one 'Add' with three items so you still have to manually defrag after each. I'm trying to find a place to do the defrag once, after I've add the controls in the CollectionChanged handler, but before it begins the layout/render process. A PrepareUiForLayout or something along those lines.

Comment: Well, that would be where `ISupportInitialize` comes in. Since WPF will call `BeginInitialize` and `EndInitialize` for you, you wouldn't defrag until `EndInitialize` is called.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but by its definition, WPF *wouldn't* call `EndInitialize` (let alone `BeginInitialize`) in response to changes of the data collection after the control is already initialized and on the screen, nor could it even know the adds have ended!  After all I can have two lines of code, each that adds a single item to the Items collection but the control wouldn't know a second one was coming after the first add.  However, *both* adds would happen before the UI actually updates.  It's in that 'gap'--after the adds but before the UI updates that I need to insert my 'defrag' call.

Comment: Well, after the `Control` has been shown, then no, WPF wouldn't do anything. But since you were talking about defining them in static XAML, that was my suggestion. As far as after it is shown, I would say you should either manually call `Begin/EndInitialize`, or implement a custom `INotifyCollectionChanged` collection that has support for `AddRange` and `RemoveRange`. I've just added another option which might get what you're after.